# Фуллскрин картинка на заднем фоне

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Хотел сделать картинку на заднем фоне, но она работает не так, как хотелось бы. При увеличении масштаба картинка остаётся такой же, а всё остальное увеличивается, а хотелось бы, чтобы она также масштабировалась. Я думаю, что скорее всего это из-за свойства `background-size: cover;`, но если его убрать, то картинка просто не помещается на странице.

100% масштаб:
[image: 1]

300% масштаб:
[image: 2]

```css
/* обнуляем стили */
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;}
*, *:before, *:after {-moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}
:focus,:active {outline: none;}
a:focus, a:active {outline: none;}
nav, footer, header, aside {display: block;}
html, body {height: 100%; width: 100%; font-size: 100%; line-height: 1; font-size: 14px; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -moz-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;}
input, button, textarea {font-family: inherit;}
input::-ms-clear {display:block;} /* для IE none, чтобы убрать крестик */
button {cursor: pointer;}
button::-moz-focus-inner {padding: 0; border: 0;}
a, a:visited {text-decoration: none;}
a:hover {text-decoration: none;}
ul li {list-style: none;}
img {vertical-align: top;}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {font-size: inherit; font-weight: 400;}
/*=================================================================*/

body {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 max-width: 1857px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.hi {
 min-height: 100vh;
 background: url(https://fanparty.ru/fanclubs/space-and-ufo/gallery/1111806_space_and_ufo.jpg) top center no-repeat;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Pex</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:700|Open+Sans:300,400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="hi">
  <header>
   <div class="hi__header_logo">
    <img src="img/icons/pex.svg" alt="" class="hi__header_logo-img">
    <img src="img/icons/logo-text.svg" alt="" class="hi__header_logo-text">
   </div>
   <nav class="hi__header_menu">
    <a href="#" class="hi__header_menu-item">About</a>
    <a href="#" class="hi__header_menu-item">How it works</a>
    <a href="#" class="hi__header_menu-item">Services</a>
    <a href="#" class="hi__header_menu-item">FAQ</a>
    <a href="#" class="hi__header_menu-item">Contact</a>
   </nav>
   <div class="hi__header_search">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search Website">
    <input type="image" src="img/icons/seach-glass.png">
   </div>
   <hr>
  </header>
  <div class="hi__content margin-content">
   <h1 class="hi__content_h1">Designs your eyeballs will thank you for </h1>
   <a href="#" class="hi__content_button">Get Started Today</a>
   <div class="hi__content_add-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: и кстати -webkit для background-size писать не надо : 2020год и всё браузеры уже знают о существовании этого css правила

Comment: @MaximLensky я добавил картинку. Префиксы я  не пишу, саблайм сам  их добавляет, а мне лень их убирать

Comment: Она не будет меняться при масштабировании. background-size: cover меняет поведение при изменений пропорций(высоты/ширины) самого блока. Как в принципе и все семейство background-size
Так как вы пропорции блока не поменяли и то фон остался таким, какой есть.

Comment: @MaximLensky да, на весь экран, но проблема ещё осталась

Comment: добавьте background-size: 100% 100%; и скажите вам такое поведение хотелось ?

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов я уже понял, что это работает и при масштабировании, хотелось бы узнать, как можно сделать так, чтобы она масштабировалась и в тоже время была на весь экран, помещаясь туда полностью

Comment: @MaximLensky я уже пробовал, ничего не изменяется